# Is it possible to determine the cause of a HPUX PA-RISC seg fault without using pmap or wdb?

Tags: c++, hp-ux

We are encountering a randomly occurring segmentation fault on a C/C++ HPUX PA-RISC application RELEASE demo compiled with the HPUX PARISC compiler and linker ACC which loads a HPUX PA_RISC RELEASE shared object sl(i.e. so) compiled and linked with ACC. We do not have access to pmap or HPUX wdb. So we are using HP's proprietary debugger adb. Here is how we use use adb:

```
$ adb
PA-32 adb ($h help $q quiit)
adb>!cp mdMUReadWriteExample a.out
!
adb>:r
a.out: running (process 10947)
segmentation violation
stopped at      1E3C:           STW             r3,1416(r1)
```

At this point it appears the offending instruction is somehow related to the above assembly insruction. Our first question is whether `1416` is in decimal format or hexadecimal format.

Our second question is whether the program counter 1E3C is accurate and can be used to gain further information about the offending C/C++ source line of code/

Our third question is that supposing `1416` is in decimal format , then as shown below register `1($r1)` contains `0x40015b90`. Using hexadecimal arithmetic `1416`(base 10(i.e. hex `0x588`)) + `0x40015b90` equals `0x40016118`. Next , we use nm to find the shared object library address / C++ mangled symbol associated with `0x40016118`.

```
$ grep -n "4001611" /home/marc/acc3_pa_32bit/cameron_nm.txt
27808:40016118 ? static___soa_RSA_cpp_
27823:40016110 ? static___soa_cDateTime_cpp_
```

Next we modify our makefile to obtain the combined disassembly -- C++ source code. However, when we search all the 50 generated *.s files we cannot mysteriously find the `static___soa_RSA_cpp_`. Have we skipped a crucial step here ?

```
adb>$r
pcoqh 0   1E3F
pcoqt 0   1E43
rp    0   0xC0209793

arg0 0  1         arg1 0   7F7F04FC  arg2 0   7F7F050 4   arg3 0   7F7F0540
sp   0  7F7F05D0  ret0 0   0         ret1 0   1           dp   0   40016390
r1   0  40015B90  r3   0   7F7F0000  r4   0   4001591 8   r5   0   3C
r6   0  20        r7   0   3E        r8   0   7F7F091 0   r9   0   40015918
r10  0  40031918  r11  0   1E800     r12  0   4001611 8   r13  0   400266A4
r14  0  3F        r15  0   3F        r16  0   3D          r17  0   3D
r18  0  3A        r19  0   7B03B764  r20  0   0xA98D4 00  r21  0   7F7F0550
r22  0  0         r31  0   1E2B      sar  0   23          sr0  0   0xA98D400
sr1  0  3848400   sr2  0   0         sr3  0   0           sr4  0   0xA98D400
```

In summary, we are trying to determine if it is possible to find the offending C/C++ source lines which cause this random seg fault. Using Centos Linux and valgrind `--tool=memcheck` we cannot find any buffer overruns. Thank you.

Comment: Here is some information on HP-UX workstation and compiler.$uname -a HP-UX purple B.11.11 U 9000/800 1996057826 unlimited-user license $ aCC -V aCC: HP ANSI C++ B3910B A.03.70. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening, I figured out how to obtain  a segmentation fault stack trace with HPUX PA-RISC. 4 steps are required 1) #include "unwind.h" #include "signal.h" 2) define an extern "C" U_STACK_TRACK(int) function prototype 3) in the main function declare a SIGSEGV handler: signal(SIGSEGV,U_STACK_TRACE). 4) In the makefile, link to libcl .Regards , Frank Tzepu Chang

$ mdMUReadWriteExample
( 0)  0xc01fef60   _sigreturn  [/usr/lib/libc.2]
( 1)  0xc2f27b90   _*ct*_7CBigNumFv_2 + 0x88  [./libmdMatchup.sl]
( 2)  0xc2f3c83c   RSADecrypt_*FPCcN21Pc + 0x24  [./libmdMatchup.sl]
( 3)  0xc2f314ec   DecryptLicense*_9mdLicenseFPCcPc + 0x44  [./libmdMatchup.sl]
( 4)  0xc2f31280   DecryptDecodeTest_*9mdLicenseFPCcT1 + 0x40  [./libmdMatchup.s
l]
( 5)  0xc2f30c3c   TestLicense*_9mdLicenseFPCc + 0xb4  [./libmdMatchup.sl]
( 6)  0xc2d783bc   SetLicenseString_*12cBatchDedupeFPCc + 0x5c  [./libmdMatchup.
sl]
( 7)  0xc2d6c908   SetLicenseString*_13mdMUReadWriteFPCc + 0x90  [./libmdMatchup
.sl]
( 8)  0x0000376c   main + 0x68  [./mdMUReadWriteExample]
( 9)  0xc01409f8   _start + 0xa0  [/usr/lib/libc.2]
(10)  0x00002008   $START$ + 0x178  [./mdMUReadWriteExample]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)